# Error while configuring pycharm with odoo-13

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm, configure, odoo-13

I am trying to configure a new project to Odoo on Windows however when I run the project after specifying **odoo-bin** as the *Script path* this error appears to my:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Odoo 13_20200903/server/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "D:\Odoo 13_20200903\server\odoo\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Any idea how can it be fixed?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have PyPDF2 installed?

Comment: yes it is installed. i was able to connect odoo server to pycharm normally but when i created a new project and tried to connect it to the server it gave me this error!

Comment: how are you running the script?  how did you install PyPDF2?  are you using the same python version that has PyPDF2 installed?

Comment: i am using python 3.8 plus i have updated The PyPDF2 using Command Line using this command : `pip install PyPDF2` @ewong

Answer (score -1):

The Python interpreter used differs from the interpreter in which the libraries are loaded, make sure that the required interpreter path,  may be inside a venv or another name.